# Emailing in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

I am trying use the `Emailing System(CakeEmail Class)` in my CakePHP application. When a new user registeres with my site, it'll send him/her an email saying that "You are saved, now follow this link to login". I added this feature, but its not sending any mail or show me whats the wrong with the code. This is the code:
p

```
App::uses('AppController','Controller','CakeEmail','Network/Email');p
.
.
.
public function signUp(){
    if($this->request->is('post')){
       $this->User->create();
       if($this->User->save($this->request->data)){
          $Email=new CakeEmail('default');
          $Email->from(array('admin_beauty_class@email.com'=>'My Site'))
                ->to($this->request->data['User']['username'])
                ->subject('Welcome to Beauty Class')
                ->send('My message');
          $this->Session->setFlash(__('You have been saved and an email has just been sent to you, check your mail-box and follow the given link to login'));
          $this->redirect();
       }else{
          $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
       }
    }
    $this->set('title_for_layout','Sign Up');
}
```

Comment: Have you verified that all of the `if` conditions are true in order for execution of the email and setFlash statements to occur? What output do you receive?

Comment: `$this->request->data['User']['username']` is a valid email address? Do a try-catch around the email and see if there's any output.

Comment: App::uses() - as documented - only takes two arguments. You need several of those to cover your classes!

Comment: Yes, all "if"s are working. And it shows " Class 'CakeEmail' not found". @GeorgeCummins

Comment: Yes, I checked it, it perfectly shows the new user's email. @Nunser

Comment: Oh, new thing, thanks. @mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
App::uses('AppController','Controller','CakeEmail','Network/Email');p
.
.
.
public function signUp(){ # ... the rest of your code
```

to

```
App::uses('AppController','Controller');
App::uses('CakeEmail','Network/Email');

public function signUp(){ # ... the rest of your code
```

**Source**

- http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/app.html#App::uses

> static App::uses(string $class, string $package)
>
> Classes are lazily loaded in CakePHP, however before the autoloader can find your classes you need to tell App, where it can find the files. By telling App which package a class can be found in, it can properly locate the file and load it the first time a class is used.

Some examples:

```
App::uses('PostsController', 'Controller');
App::uses('AuthComponent', 'Controller/Component');
App::uses('MyModel', 'Model');
```

> So basically the second param should simply match the folder path of the class file in core or app.

---

Ps. give [Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17240134/emailing-in-cakephp/17242602#comment24984251_17240134) some credits. I didn't notice that the answer was already given in the comments.

Comment: You gave a specific example @Jelmer

Comment: @user2387319 don't forget to accept it as an answer if it did solve it for you. In case other SO users find this question.

Comment: @user2387319 Hit the green tick on the left of the question. Right below the votes.

Comment: Ok, I accepted it. Now, can you please tell me, why its not recognizing the "CakeEmail" class ? @Jelmer

Comment: @user2387319 it's not a trade or something. We talk about that over [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17259273/1110760)

Comment: Oh, I am so sorry, I didn't mean that, I am eagerly waiting for a solution. If my comment hurts you, I am so so sorry. @Jelmer

Comment: @user2387319 It doesn't hurt me. But have a look at the other question. I made a comment but you did not respond if that was the case. We are going to put several days of effort in your question if you don't show us what you did and if any of our help so far did get you any further ;-)